# building a function equivalent to memcpy

Tags: c

I am learning `C` and `C++` and I am trying to find an equivalent of: `memcpy((char *) (m + 1), &e, sizeof(int))` in C or C++ i.e. I am trying to construct my own `memcpy` function. I tried to use the following pointer movement:

```
std::string s = std::to_string(5);
void *ptr=m;
char *charPtr=(char*)ptr;
++charPtr = const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());
```

However I find that this is not equivalent to C's `memcpy((char *) (m + 1), &e, sizeof(int))`. Can someone please suggest as to where am I going wrong. My full code snippet is given below:

```
enum MT {A,B,C};

typedef struct M{
    enum MT mT;
}M;


int main(){
    M *m = (M*) malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    int e=5;

    //finding an equivalent of memcpy((char *) (m + 1), &e, sizeof(int)); START
    std::string s = std::to_string(5);
    void *ptr=m;
    char *charPtr=(char*)ptr;
    ++charPtr = const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());             
    //finding an equivalent of memcpy((char *) (m + 1), &e, sizeof(int)); END
}
```

Comment: I don't even understand what you want your code to do. It looks very wrong.

Comment: Ok... actually I am trying to build my own memcpy. Please help me correct as to where am I going wrong

Comment: @Steg: I think your'e biggest problem is that you don't seem to be building memcpy. I don't see any function with prototype something like `void my_memcpy(char *destination, const char *source, size_t num)` (or maybe with `void*` arguments). Also, you don't yet seem to have tried to do anything that actually tries to read data from a source so that it can write it to a destination.

Comment: Ok..probably I am going wrong but I dont know where..I am sorry for my noviceness..can you please help me understand this with the help of an example

Comment: You cannot learn *C and C++* ; these are different languages. You could *learn C* and *learn C++* (like you could learn French and learn German, but there is no such language as "French and German")

Comment: I voted to close the question because it is so unclear.

Comment: can you explain what you think `++charPtr = something;` is trying to do? (this is not legal code)

Comment: For a start, in C you would never cast an argument to `memcpy` the way you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that C and C++ are *different* languages (but C++ have been designed to be friendly with a *subset* of C). You cannot learn C and C++, you can learn C and learn C++. Likewise you cannot learn "French and German" (there is no such language) but you can learn French and learn German.

Read more about C++, notably standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) & [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)-s & [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm); you probably should consider using `std::vector<M>` or `std::array<M>` (instead of your `malloc`-ed pointer `m` ...)

[memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) is rarely useful (but it is useful).

Notice that [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)-s have many modifier functions: [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert), [replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) etc...

---

If you want to understand how `memcpy` is implemented, look for [memcpy implementation](https://jlmedina123.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/memcpy-implementation/)s. However, in practice, it is so important that it might be (for performance reasons) using some compiler builtin, like e.g. [__builtin_memcpy](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). But that is an implementation detail (but quite an important one).

In theory,  `memcpy` could be naively implemented in C as e.g.

```
void my_memcpy(void*dst, const void*src, size_t siz)
{
   char*pdst = dst;
   const char*psrc = src;
   for (size_t ix=0; ix<siz; ix++) 
      pdst[ix] = psrc[ix];
}
```

and there are other popular variants like

```
   while (siz-->0) *(pdst++) = *(psrc++);
```

but in practice, a computer can copy much faster memory blocks using entire [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) or even using [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor) machine instructions ([SSE4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4), [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), etc etc....). But to do that it has to deal with additional machine constraints (e.g. data alignment), and the evil is in the details.

---

BTW, your code is very wrong. You are assuming that `sizeof(M)` is 1. It might not be. Then your `m` pointer might not have enough space.

I would suggest (assuming you are on Linux with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler) at least compiling with all warnings and debug info `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g` and use the `gdb` debugger to step by step into your code.

BTW, on my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9, the following program

```
#include <iostream>

enum MT{A,B,C};

typedef struct M{
    enum MT mT;
}M;

int main() {
  std::cout << "sizeof(M)=" << sizeof(M) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

is displaying

```
sizeof(M)=4
```

so your code is entire non-sense ([undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)). I don't even understand what you want it to do!

PS. I'm not sure you'll get helpful answers here. Your misunderstanding of C++ is so big that you need to take days or weeks to read an entire book (or even more) about C++. And if you want to also learn C, you'll need other weeks to read a book about C and practice it. We can't offer such long answers here. The notion of *undefined behavior* is important: even if your code don't crash your machine, it can be *very wrong*

Comment: Ok..can you please explain with an example..perhaps how I can do it with struct M* will be very helpful

Comment: Ok but my code works perfecty when I use memcpy((char *) (m + 1), &e, sizeof(int)). But it is not working with pointer arithmetic. Can you please help me with how can I correct the code

Comment: Basically, genuine C++ is about *avoiding* raw pointers and pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Yes but I want to copy data to pointer locations. Is there no way other than using pointers by which I can achieve the same

Comment: My point is that you should avoid raw pointers. I don't understand why you use them, and I don't even understand what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Actually I am trying to learn pointers, so instead of using memcpy I am trying to build my own memcpy operation..using  std::string s = std::to_string(5);
            void *ptr=m+1;
            char *charPtr=(char*)ptr;
            charPtr = const_cast<char*>(s.c_str());  but I dont know where am I going wrong

Comment: Ok. I am sorry I'll edit my question. Thanks for correcting me. What does (char *) (m + 1) mean, does it mean move pointer to structure M by 1 or does it mean move the character pointer by 1

Comment: I don't have the patience and time (it would take me weeks) to teach you C++; you have to read a good book about C++ programming (it is hard and will requires weeks of effort from your part!) and/or follow some courses. And StackOverflow is not an online course or lecture service!

Comment: @StegVerner it means to take the address in memory of the first byte after the end of what `m` points to, and pretend that it contains `char` values

Comment: @MattMcNabb: you are wrong, not the first byte, but the first element of the type of ̀ `*m`: in the OP code, that type is a 4 byte `struct`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's what I mean by "what m points to"

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), although `memcpy()` continues to work in the same kind situations where it works in C (that is, when you *know* that the structure can be copied byte-by-byte without breaking things).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not getting how can I use copy(). Can you please explain this with the help of an example. I'll be very thankful to you for the same

Comment: The linked page has an example.

Comment: Thanks again. But the example is for vectors. I am not getting how can I use the same example for my struct M*. Please an example pertaining to my example will help me clarify my doubt. Sorry for my noviceness...but i am really not getting

Comment: The `std::copy()` function just takes iterators.  You can use iterators for a `std::vector` or a `std::string` just fine, the syntax is the same.

Comment: Yes but I want to achieve something which memcpy achieves with memcpy((char *) (m + 1), &e, sizeof(int)); and I dont have vectors here

Comment: You can still use `std::memcpy()`, nobody is stopping you.

Comment: Yes I can. But I am trying to find an alternative way for copying data at pointer locations. It has very useful applications while performing serializations.

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? What is wrong with `std::memcpy()` that you need an alternative for it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with memcpy. I am trying to learn pointers..so I want to figure out where my code is going wrong (In the code I am not using memcpy)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you if you're not trying to solve a specific problem.

Comment: memcpy() is a function, so it must have an equivalent code..I am just trying to figure out that equivalent code with the help with pointer movement. I hope now I am clear

Comment: @StegVerner: no you are not clear at all, and you should edit your question to improve it, not explain it in comments!